# Gmail suspicious link message on my email links

Tags: email, gmail

My site sends emails to users, gmail has an issue with the links on these emails. On click of my links a message comes up saying:

> suspicious link- this was sent from untrusted site. You sure you want to proceed?

Has anyone come upon this and overcome it? If so, how?

Details: my emails use smtp, have dkim, spf, and dmarc, they all pass. spam score 0.8, which is low.
The link is different than the text.

The anchor href sends the user to youtube actually, and the text of which is the title of the video user is directed to.
OR it is a link to activation page, text is "Click to Activate".

My site is https and of course gmail and youtube are https.

Comment: "The link is different than the text." - Just to clarify, the text is just ordinary text, it's not text that looks like an alternative URL or something silly like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer lies in the trustworthiness of the sender. 
I needed to clean up my CNAME, A, DMARC, TXT records.

I recommend skimming this youtube video for more details.
[Holy Trinity of Email Delivery](https://youtu.be/3BV7z1Pi89Q)

My emails are now trustworthy according to Google.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `http`, you may need to make the switch to `https`.

Check your IP address to make sure it's clean. You can check your blacklist status here: [MX Toolbox](https://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx).

Comment: see edits above

Comment: My link already used https, and the MX Toolbox didn't find problems. So I don't know why Gmail suddenly started showing warnings about my site (for a site and email that has worked fine for months or years).

Comment: See my recent answer

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that if you use PUBLIC Url shorteners (bit.ly etc). They all will be flagged regardless as to whether your domain has been flagged